# .intersect in android studio

Tags: java, android

im trying to make a air hockey game, and I'm having some troubles with collisions, the command intersect doesn't work for me:

```
        if(rocket1.getShape().intersect(ball.getShape())  || ball.getShape().intersect(rocket1.getShape()))
    {
        //changing ball moving direction
        ball.playerBounce(rocket1.getShape());
        ball.speedUP2(100);
    }
```

also, do you have any idea, how can I handle ball bouncing?

Comment: `doesn't work for me` how exactly?

Comment: even if the ball's rectF is in the center of player's rectF, it doesn't gets inside this if statement

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NAUpFUH.png

Comment: are you sure that it check frequently enough so it just does not skip it?

Comment: it is in the same loop which update objects positions, so this should be fine, also my secound if does work:

Comment: else if(ball.getShape().bottom < rocket2.getShape().top & ball.getShape().left + ball.getSizeX() > rocket2.getShape().left & ball.getShape().right - ball.getSizeX()< rocket2.getShape().right & ball.getShape().bottom + 2*ball.getSizeX() > rocket2.getShape().top)
        {
            //changing ball moving direction
            ball.playerBounce(rocket2.getShape());
            ball.speedUP2(100);
        }

Comment: what I noticed is that your `if` checks against `rocket1`, but your `else` checks against `rocket2`. Are you sure that you are checking correct rocket?

Comment: yes, the rocket 2 is on the other side of the field, and the collision works for it, but id does not for rocket 1, which uses intersect method